# How to run run task schedule

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the code :

```
public static async Task Download()
        {
            var urls = new[] {
        "https://github.com/naudio/NAudio",
        "https://twitter.com/mark_heath",
        "https://github.com/markheath/azure-functions-links",
        "https://pluralsight.com/authors/mark-heath",
        "https://github.com/markheath/advent-of-code-js",
        "http://stackoverflow.com/users/7532/mark-heath",
        "https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/mvp/Mark%20%20Heath-5002551",
        "https://github.com/markheath/func-todo-backend",
        "https://github.com/markheath/typescript-tetris",};

            var client = new HttpClient();
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                Console.WriteLine($"retrieved {html.Length} characters from {url}");
            }
        }
```

The all task client.GetStringAsync(url) will execute as the same time. But I wanna call client.GetStringAsync each url after timeout (no need to await the previous task complete). Ex :

```
at 00:00:01 - GetStringAsync url1 
at 00:00:05 - GetStringAsync url2
at 00:00:09 - GetStringAsync url3
```

Each task will be started after 4 seconds. So how can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to await the querying of the url, then *don't await it*.  If you want to run the continuation after 4 seconds (or any other fixed period of time), then use `Task.Delay`.

```
public static async Task Download()
{
    var urls = new[] {
        "https://github.com/naudio/NAudio",
        "https://twitter.com/mark_heath",
        "https://github.com/markheath/azure-functions-links",
        "https://pluralsight.com/authors/mark-heath",
        "https://github.com/markheath/advent-of-code-js",
        "http://stackoverflow.com/users/7532/mark-heath",
        "https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/mvp/Mark%20%20Heath-5002551",
        "https://github.com/markheath/func-todo-backend",
        "https://github.com/markheath/typescript-tetris",};

    var client = new HttpClient();

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        ProcessURL(url);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
    }

    async Task ProcessURL(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            Console.WriteLine($"retrieved {html.Length} characters from {url}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //TODO handle any errors in processing the URL
        }
    }
}
```

Note that since nothing is awaiting `ProcessURL`, it'll need to be responsible for handling any errors that might happen internally, since no caller will be able to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to wait 4 seconds between tech call, instead of waiting for the previous call to complete?

You can use `Task.Delay` for that -

```
public static async Task Download()
        {
            var urls = new[] {
        "https://github.com/naudio/NAudio",
        "https://twitter.com/mark_heath",
        "https://github.com/markheath/azure-functions-links",
        "https://pluralsight.com/authors/mark-heath",
        "https://github.com/markheath/advent-of-code-js",
        "http://stackoverflow.com/users/7532/mark-heath",
        "https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/mvp/Mark%20%20Heath-5002551",
        "https://github.com/markheath/func-todo-backend",
        "https://github.com/markheath/typescript-tetris",};

            var client = new HttpClient();
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                var waitingTask = Task.Delay(1000 * 4); //4000 milliseconds
                var fireAndForget = client.GetStringAsync(url);
                await waitingTask;

            }
        }
```

A couple of things to notice here -

1. If sending the HTTP call takes
   more than 4 seconds, your code will be delayed for the amount of
   time it takes to send it out, even if it's more than 4 seconds.
2. By
   not waiting for the HTTP call to complete, you can't use the
   resulting HTML

You can solve this issue with something like a continuation -

```
client.GetStringAsync(url).ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine($"retrieved {task.Result.Length} characters from {url}"));
```

**Edit - adding for completeness as per @Servy's comment -**

My continuation example above is very partial, and meant to convey the idea of handling the result of a task that was not awaited. There are multiple ways to handle the the download process, both in terms of using the result and of handling errors. Here is an approach that uses `ContinueWith`, but checks to see how the download completed instead of assuming is succeeded -

```
        var task = client.GetStringAsync(url);
        task.ContinueWith(task => 
        {
            // task completed correctly, do something with the result, like - 
            Console.WriteLine($"retrieved {task.Result.Length} characters from {url}");
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        task.ContinueWith(task => 
        {
            // task did not complete successfully, you can check why using the task iteslf, for example 
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                // the task failed with an unhandled exception, you can access the exception instance if you want, for example - 
                Console.WriteLine($"Error while downloading from {url} - {task.Exception}");
            }
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
```

Comment: Using `ContinueWith` won't result in proper error handling semantics for handling the actual processing of the task.

Comment: @Servy - Added a section to show how `Task.ContinueWith` can be used to handle exceptions correctly

Answer (score -1):

Use Task.Delay [Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.7.2)
and wait 4  secands between each call

HttpClientHelper: HTTPrequest Wrapper

HttpResult: wrap request result

```
    public static async Task Download()
    {
        HttpClientHelper clientHelper = new HttpClientHelper();
        List<HttpResult> httpResults = new List<HttpResult>();
        var urls = new[] {
            "https://github.com/naudio/NAudio",
            "https://twitter.com/mark_heath",
            "https://github.com/markheath/azure-functions-links",
            "https://pluralsight.com/authors/mark-heath",
            "https://github.com/markheath/advent-of-code-js",
            "https://stackoverflow.com/users/7532/mark-heath",
            "https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/mvp/Mark%20%20Heath-5002551",
            "https://github.com/markheath/func-todo-backend",
            "https://github.com/markheath/typescript-tetris",};

        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            HttpResult httpResult = clientHelper.GetStringAsync(url);
            httpResults.Add(httpResult);
            if (httpResult.HasError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: '{httpResult.Error}' on characters from {url}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"retrieved {httpResult.Result.Length} characters from {url}");

            }

            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }

public class HttpClientHelper
{
    public async Task<HttpResult> GetStringAsync(string url)
    {
        HttpResult httpResult = new HttpResult
        {
            URL = url
        };
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            httpResult.Result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //todo:handel Exception
            httpResult.HasError = true;
            httpResult.Error = e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.InnerException?.Message;
        }
        return httpResult;
    }
}

public class HttpResult
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public bool HasError { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```